# TFS GIT Pull Request report?

Tags: git, tfs, report, pull-request

It may be unusual, but for regulation purpose we need to prove that there was a pull request completed for each commit to the develop branch.

I know about branch policies, but the best solution would be a report which contains, for all commits in a time period:

- Pull request id
- Status (completed)
- Reviewer(s)

or similar.

Did someone ever implement such, or similar report? Any suggestions on how to approach this task?

(Branch policies are insufficient because, in theory, a person with sufficient access rights may turn off the policy, commit code and turn back on the policy).

Comment: The idea that branch policies aren't sufficient because someone with sufficient rights can disable it is silly. You might as well not store source code in Azure DevOps because someone with sufficient rights can delete the repository, or **even the entire team project**. If you have concerns about privilege levels, audit your privilege levels and ensure that only appropriate people have privileges you're concerned about.

Comment: Of course I know it is silly. It is a regulated industry, however (medical device software) so it is not always up to me to decide how to proceed. The audit idea sound interesting, people here love audits. :(

Comment: Hi Evgeny, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. We still encourage you to use pull request just make sure appropriate users which have the permission to turn on or off branch policies.  And then use git pull request report as the assistant way to monitor all generated pull requests. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for  marking it as an answer which will also helps others in the community.

Comment: Hi Patrick, yes, your information was exactly what I needed. I will use the REST API and then add some processing as the API does not allow searching for a date range, for example, but these details are easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hard if you want to obtain a report of pending pull requests, or even completed pull requests, you can use widget available here in your dashboards.

Such as this 3rd-party extension-- [Pull Request Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanstedman.tfs-pullrequest-dashboard)

However, if you want a custom report, you can use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20threads/list?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) and create your own report. It will retrieve all threads in a pull request:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/threads?api-version=4.1
```

More details you could take a look at this blog--[Pull Request Report for Azure Git Repos](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2019/01/pull-request-report-for-azure-git-repos.html)

However, this could not make sure every generated commit has a pull request. For this, you need to use branch policy to handle it.